# Independent joint conditional probability

Tags: probability, distributions

I am new to conditional probability. I would like to do some inference. If we know p(z|x) and p(z|y), can we infer p(z|x,y)? What can we deduce if x and y are independent? Thank you very much.

Comment: Although I cannot trace the questions and answers, I am sure this question has been asked on CV in the past. In any case, there is no answer to this question with this insufficient amount of information.

Comment: Thanks Xi'an. I have tried the following: p(z|x, y) = p(z,x|y)p(y)/p(x,y). Assume that x and y are independent, the RHS becomes: p(z,x|y)p(y)/p(x,y) = p(z,x|y)/p(x). I don't know how to proceed then. Alternatively,  p(z|x, y) = p(x,y|z)p(z)/p(x,y). If x, y are independent, can we write p(x,y|z) = p(x|z)p(y|z)?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in $p(z|x)$ and $p(z|x)$ to determine $p(z|x,y)$. In particular, when $X$ and $Y$ are independent, they may become dependent conditional on $Z$: take for instance the exponential variates $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, related by
$$X\sim\mathcal{E}(1)\qquad Y\sim\mathcal{E}(1)\qquad Z|X,Y\sim\mathcal{E}(XY)$$
In this case, 
$$Y|X,Z\sim f(y|x,z)\propto xy\exp\{-y-xyz\}$$
is a Gamma$(2,1+xz)$ that depends on $x$.

Comment: Could you briefly explain what your notation "$\mathcal E$" means?